# Multiple Files In One Project - C

Tags: c, xcode, linker-errors

Since I am just now learning C I want to be able to create one "Projects" folder in XCode to hold all my mini files that I create to learn different stuff. Such as `HelloWorld.c` `IfElse.c` `WhleLoop.c` however I am having a major issue. I can't run these different `main` files without getting the error below...

```
duplicate symbol _main error: 
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is the easiest way to go about this? I want to only have one project open in Xcode to be able to very easily reference my previous files and just create little tests files that do different learning things before I really get into C.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

-Henry

Comment: You want to create only one executable only out of this or you one executable for each of them?

Comment: @KranthiKumar I want to be able to execute each file separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is to write Makefile

Open one new file with the name "Makefile"

In that file type as given below:

```
all:hello ifelse while

hello:HelloWorld.o
<tab>cc -o hello  HelloWorld.o

ifelse:IfElse.o
<tab>cc -o ifelse IfElse.o

WhileLoop.o:WhileLoop.o
<tab>cc -o while WhileLoop.o
```

The above given is a makefile which are used for creating multiple executables under a single project in Linux. It is also available in standard sdks like Eclipse. For any new file you want compile add it to the makefile as shown for other files.

Once you finish writing the makefile enter the command make in the terminal.

Everything will get compiled and different executables get created.

To know more about the makefile you can refer to the below link:

http://www.cs.wmich.edu/~sdflemin/instr_pgs/make/index.html